# How to create single slash string in terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I want to form a file system attach command string in terraform.

For example i want to form the following command string

```
"net use Z: \\fs-0e711dfff4523c0bcbbe6a.example.com\share"
```

I am am trying following script

```
fs_attach_command = format("%s%s%s%s%s","net use Z: ", "\\",  aws_fsx_windows_file_system.fsx_windows_file_system[project.name].dns_name, "\\","share")
```

But this return

```
"net use Z: \\fs-0e711dfff4523c0bcbbe6a.example.com\\share"
```

Terraform version is v1.0.8

What is the correct way to do this in terraform?

Comment: How about putting a single slash in your 4th parameter instead of a double one?

Comment: @vele did not work. string format issue is retuned

Comment: What error do you get? You should edit your question to show the alternate version you tried and the error you got from it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Terraform inherits the C-like convention of using a backslash as an escape character inside quoted string templates, and so if you want your *final* string (the result after evaluation) to include a literal backslash then you need to escape it, by writing two backslashes `\\`.

In your case you have a situation where you want your resulting string to contain two consecutive backslashes, and so you'll need to escape each one of those separately, which means four consecutive backslashes in the source program: `\\\\`.

Putting that all together, we get:

```
"net use Z: \\\\${aws_fsx_windows_file_system.fsx_windows_file_system[project.name].dns_name}\\share
```

Each one of those pairs of backslashes will become a single backslash in the resulting string, giving the result you wanted:

```
net use Z: \\fs-0e711dfff4523c0bcbbe6a.example.com\share
```

Note that Terraform typically shows strings in its UI in quotes as you'd write them in the source code, so Terraform is likely to show this value in the plan as `"net use Z: \\\\fs-0e711dfff4523c0bcbbe6a.example.com\\share"`, and so you need to mentally evaluate those escape sequences yourself in order to see the actual string value.

---

Since this seems to be a Windows batch program or similar, it might not matter if you had a newline character on the end of this string, and therefore it might be reasonable to write this instead as a multi-line ["heredoc" string template](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/strings.html#heredoc-strings) instead, which avoids the need for backslash escaping because Terraform takes backslashes literally in this template syntax:

```
fs_attach_command = <<-EOT
  net use Z: \\${aws_fsx_windows_file_system.fsx_windows_file_system[project.name].dns_name}\share
EOT
```

This form is arguably more readable because it doesn't include any escaping and the only non-literal part is the template interpolation sequence `${ .. }`. However, because this is now a multi-line string, the final value of this will include a newline character at the end which may or may not be appropriate depending on how you will eventually use this string. Terraform has no "heredoc" template syntax for single-line strings.